# "Search Pane" element not found exception in win 8 app

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a win 8 app in visual studio 2012 which implements search contract. To enable search functionality I have added "search pane" element. But while running the app I am getting an exception

```
"Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"
```

for the code -

```
this.searchPane = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView()
```

can anyone tell me what is problem and solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems usually occur from XAML markups. Make sure everything is ok in your page markup files, that search pane element in described in appropriate way, without redundant or missing attributes.

Comment: Simply calling SearchPane.GetForCurrentView() seems to crash on a Desktop app, regardless of the XAML markup.

Comment: I have the same problem in an Windows 8.1 app. The funny thing is. I have two development machines, both with Windows 8.1 Enterprise. The only difference between those machines is that the one has an SSD, where the second has an HDD, Both machines are running the same image. On the first machine (with SSD) the exception occurs, on the other it runs fine. I am pretty sure, that the SSD is not the solution! But what can it be??