# Cannot open the Windows Search Pane in WPF: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime, charms-bar

I have a WPF project with only these changes from an empty project:

- This line added to the .csproj: `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>`
- A reference added to `Windows`
- A button with a Click handler executing this: `SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().Show("test");`

When I click the button, I have an exception when calling `.GetForCurrentView()`:

`Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)`

What can I do to diagnose it and make it work?

---

Details:

Note that I have no breakpoints, I'm running on Windows 8.1 and I already tried:

- Adding `await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();` before;
- Adding a 1000ms delay;
- Referencing `System.Runtime`, `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`

I know I can use SendKeys to send `Win` + `S` + `(query)`, but this is exactly what I'm trying to replace since at the moment I try to open the search charm, the `Ctrl` key will be down (launched by a shortcut).

Comment: Linking question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742558/search-pane-element-not-found-exception-in-win-8-app since it is the same error, but this question is with WPF

Comment: You cannot use WinRT classes in a WPF app, this is supposed to fail.

Comment: @HansPassant to you have a reference? There are articles on doing this on MSDN blogs (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I found the reference myself: WinRT is supported, but SearchPane specifically is not supported... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though some WinRT API functions can be used in a desktop app, `SearchPane` cannot.

MSDN pages show whether each individual API function can be used or not in Desktop apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.aspx